# Finding expectation given a joing distribution function

Tags: probability

[image]

### Attempt

I havent yet learned about expectation of joint distribution. But, what I think is to find marginal distribution of $Y$

$$ f_Y(y) = \int_0^{\infty} f_{XY}(x,y) = 6 e^{-2y} $$

So,

$$ E(Y) = \int\limits_0^{\infty} y 6 e^{-2y} $$

is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Since $0<x<y<\infty$, then $$E[XY]=\int_{x=0}^\infty\int_{y=x}^\infty xy \,f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: This should give same answer as $E(Y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a particular value of $y$, note that $x$ is bounded above by $y$.

\begin{align}f_Y(y) &= \int_0^y 6 \exp(-x) \exp(-2y ) \,dx \\&=-6\exp(-2y) \exp(-x) \mid _0^y\\&=6\exp(-2y) (1-\exp(-y)) \end{align}